# Why doesn't PIP Install work for PDFMiner?

Tags: python, pdfminer

I am trying to PIP Install PDFMiner and I am getting a Syntax Error.

Using PIP install as admin

py -m pip install PDFMinner

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ryan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-61x3fs8f\\PDFMiner\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ryan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-61x3fs8f\\PDFMiner\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
     cwd: C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-61x3fs8f\PDFMiner\
Complete output (8 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-61x3fs8f\PDFMiner\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pdfminer import __version__
  File "C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-61x3fs8f\PDFMiner\pdfminer\__init__.py", line 5
    print __version__
                    ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(__version__)?
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Looks like Py2.x syntax is trying to be run in Py3. Uninstall it and try ```pip3 install <package>

Comment: So after a quick google search, you need to ```pip install pdfminer.six``` for Py3.x Link: https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six

Comment: @JoshuaNixon want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

PDFMiner is for Py2.x, after some googling I found that the Py3.x version can be installed by running `pip install pdfminer.six`

Link to the GitHub where I found this: https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six